# Cant load module in controller - NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I load my services module if I have this directory and file structure:

`MarketShare::Foo` in
`app/services/market_share/foo.rb`

So I can access this module with rails console (eg: `MarketShare::Foo`), but in my controller `Report::MarketSharesController` in `app/controllers/report/market_shares_controller.rb` I get this error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Report::MarketSharesController::Foo
```

when I call with `MarketShare::Foo`.

I have insert this path in autoloads too:

```
config.autoload_paths.push(Rails.root.join('app/services/market_share'))
```

but I got the same error again.

EDITED: Guys, i try stop `rails server` and stop `spring` too, but the error persist.

Comment: stop rails, then stop spring (bin/spring stop) and lastly start your rails app again

Comment: Thanks, I make this and nothings happen. I got the same error. I remove Spring too, but, the same error again.

Comment: can you show how you call and include `MarketShare::Foo` module from the controller ?

Comment: Can you try `::MarketShare::Foo` with the leading scope resolution operator? It looks like you might have a module name resolution conflict.  It will be good to know if you can access it from the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this configuration:

> config.autoload_paths.push(Rails.root.join('app/services/market_share'))

Try following:

> 1- STOP Rails: CRTL + z
>
> 2- STOP Spring: bin/spring stop
>
> 3- START Rails: bin/rails s

Reload your app

Comment: Thanks, but I make this and nothings happen. I got the same error. I remove Spring too, but I got the same error again.

Comment: @LondersonAraújo can you show how you call MarketShare::Foo module from the controller ?

Comment: Foo is a class, and MarketShare is a namespace so, i call: `MarketShare::Foo.new(params).commit`